# How do I remove the extra characters from a string?

Tags: r

I have got a column of strings that looks like this:

[image: column of the strings]

I want to remove everything after `.html` wherever it's applicable.

For example - I want to replace

```
"/abeers-khadi-brown-heena.html?root=search&searchterm=heena&type=product&ptype=product"
```

with

```
"/abeers-khadi-brown-heena.html"
```

How do I do this for the entire column?

Comment: Don't post images of data. A hint: use regex.

Comment: To explain what @Heroka tries to say: if you post images of data, people trying more complicate problems have to retype everything. Best use the result of dput(). Not so difficult here, because regexers can do this brain-only, but that's an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But here you go: a regex.

```
    testvars <- c("adkjfa;iejaoejf;ai.html/ajdakflj", "abc.html","abcd.html?root=")

    res <- gsub("(.+\\.html).+","\\1",testvars)
    > res
[1] "adkjfa;iejaoejf;ai.html" "abc.html"               
[3] "abcd.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a package you can use for such purposes called `urltools`. Borrowing the example created by @Heroka,

```
library(urltools)
url_parse(testvars)
  scheme                  domain port     path parameter fragment
#1   <NA> adkjfa;iejaoejf;ai.html <NA> ajdakflj      <NA>     <NA>
#2   <NA>                abc.html <NA>     <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#3   <NA>               abcd.html <NA>     <NA>     root=     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to replace one of your strings using sub().

```
sub(".html.*", '.html', '/abeers-khadi-abeers-aloe-face-wash.html?root=sear')
```

This is how you would apply it to a data frame.  Here is a mock of your data.

```
rawdata <- c(
  '/a-derma/foaming-gel.html',
  '/abeers-khadi-abeers-aloe-face-wash.html?root=sear',
  '/abeers-khadi-abeers-saffron-and-neem-face-wash.html?foo=bar'
)
df <- data.frame(previousPagePath=rawdata)
```

Then I used apply with the sub() then assigned it back to the column.

```
df['previousPagePath'] <- apply(df['previousPagePath'], 1, function(x) sub(".html.*", '.html', x) )
```

Proof:

```
df

#                                       previousPagePath
# 1                            /a-derma/foaming-gel.html
# 2             /abeers-khadi-abeers-aloe-face-wash.html
# 3 /abeers-khadi-abeers-saffron-and-neem-face-wash.html
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Isn't sub/gsub vectorized?

Comment: Hi @Heroka, my R is still not that strong ... maybe you can help explain.  It will not work with 
sub( .., .. , df['previousPagePath'])

but this works.
sub( .., .. , df[,c('previousPagePath')])